# How can I enable/disable cells using Vaadin table component?

Tags: vaadin

I have a table with 2 columns: a checkbox and a textfield. I want to disable the textfield depending of the respective (same row) checkbox status. If the checkbox is checked then the textfield will be cleared and be read only. Is this possible ? Here is my code:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
private Table filtersTable() {
    final Table table = new Table();
    table.setPageLength(10);
    table.setSelectable(false);
    table.setImmediate(true);
    table.setSizeFull();
    // table.setMultiSelectMode(MultiSelectMode.SIMPLE) ;
    table.addContainerProperty("Tipo filtro", CheckBox.class, null);
    table.addContainerProperty("Valor", String.class, null);
    table.setEditable(true);
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
        TextField t = new TextField();
        t.setData(i);
        t.setMaxLength(50);
        t.setValue("valor " + i);
        t.setImmediate(true);
        t.setWidth(30, UNITS_PERCENTAGE);
        CheckBox c = new CheckBox(" filtro " + i);
        c.setWidth(30, UNITS_PERCENTAGE);
        c.setData(i);
        c.setImmediate(true);
        c.addListener(new ValueChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void valueChange(ValueChangeEvent event) {
              // within this, could I access the respective row ID
              // (i) then enable/disable TextField t on second column ?
              System.out.println("event.getProperty().getValue()="
                        + event.getProperty().getValue());
            }
        });
        table.addItem(new Object[] { c, t }, i);
    }
    return table;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Few changes to your code made it possible. 
Not the finiest way, but te simpliest.

First,you have to set your second column (Valor) to `TextField.class` not `String.class`.

Here the change :

```
table.addContainerProperty("Valor", TextField.class, null);
```

Instead of keepin the variable i in the `CheckBox.setData()`, I suggest you to link your checkBox to the TextField of the same row, like this :

```
c.setData(t);
```

Finally I made little change to your listener :

```
c.addListener(new Property.ValueChangeListener() {
            public void valueChange(ValueChangeEvent event) {

                CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)event.getProperty();
                if((Boolean) checkBox.getValue())
                {
                    TextField associatedTextField = (TextField)checkBox.getData();

                    //Do all your stuff with the TextField
                    associatedTextField.setReadOnly(true);
                }
            }
        });
```

Hope it's work for you!

Regards, Éric

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class MyCheckBox extends CheckBox {

    private TextBox t;

    public MyCheckBox(TextBox t) {

     this.t = t;
    attachLsnr();
    }

    private void attachLsnr()
    {
     addListener(new Property.ValueChangeListener() {
                public void valueChange(ValueChangeEvent event) {

                    CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)event.getProperty();
                    if((Boolean) checkBox.getValue())
                    {
                        t.setReadOnly(true);
                    }
                }
            });


    }

 }
```

Comment: Please avoid just posting code, but rather explain the code you posted so the OP will understand what you did and this site does not turn into a "write code for me please" site.